# Conditions of a function

Tags: python

(Python 3.3.2) I have to write a function def numb(a, b, c, d, e) and the values of a, b, c ,d ,e can only be  3,5, or 7, so how can i write such a condition, i tried putting them all in one line separating them by and and or however it is not working... btw the user will input those values and if they enter a number that is not 3, 5, 7 then i would have to return the function until they do (don't worry about this part, i know how to do it, I'm only having trouble writing the condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `all` with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

```
def numb(a, b, c, d, e):
    assert all(x in {3, 5, 7} for x in (a, b, c, d, e))
```

---

Another way is to use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
def numb(a, b, c, d, e):
    assert {a, b, c, d, e} <= {3, 5, 7}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, you are quite fast!

Comment: Python 3.3 >= 2.7, so set literals are available too.

Comment: I apologize but we have not yet learnt the function assert and therefore, we cannot use it, the only possible way to do it with what we've learnt is through the regular if or by writing the if statement multiple times, if that's the case can u show me how to do it for a ,b ???

Comment: I love that you always write the most useful and valid, but beginner unfriendly answers. I learn things, and the lazy OP will get questioned by their teacher. Everyone wins!

Comment: @TalatZaitoun, just replace `assert ...` with `if ...:`